# Implementing a view-model-first approach inside a parent view/view model using MEFedMVVM

Tags: wpf, mef, datatemplate, mefedmvvm

I am writing a WPF application using MEF and a third-party library called [MEFedMVVM](http://mefedmvvm.codeplex.com).

I am attempting to create a design whereby a parent view model has a collection of child view models, and I wish to use the view-model-first approach as this keeps the views outside of the view models thereby keeping the code more view model-centric and more unit testable.

I have read [this discussion](http://mefedmvvm.codeplex.com/discussions/270277) and [this discussion](http://mefedmvvm.codeplex.com/discussions/300184) regarding using DataTemplate for the view, and also Reed Copsy, Jr's suggestion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/wpf/thread/a1ac2e19-9137-417d-8144-6562e51f5a09) to use a generic view to view model mapping resource.  But, I'm struggling to actually implement something that works.

My parent view is very simple:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyParentView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:meffed="clr-namespace:MEFedMVVM.ViewModelLocator;assembly=MEFedMVVM.WPF"
             meffed:ViewModelLocator.ViewModel="MyParentViewModel" />
```

The parent view model derives from a base type that implements *IContextAware*:

```
[ExportViewModel("MyParentViewModel")]
public class MyParentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyParentViewModel()
    {
        var myChildVM = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyChildViewModel>());
    }
}
```

This is the child view model:

```
[Export(typeof(MyChildViewModel))]
[ExportViewModel("MyChildViewModel", true)]
public class MyChildViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
}
```

And this has a corresponding view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyChildView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:meffed="clr-namespace:MEFedMVVM.ViewModelLocator;assembly=MEFedMVVM.WPF"
             meffed:ViewModelLocator.ViewModel="MyChildViewModel" />
```

Initially, I thought that specifying the second Boolean parameter on *ExportViewModel* attribute for *MyChildViewModel* would make everything work using a view-model-first approach as my views and view models are MEFed together in the views' XAML code.  However, turns out this is not the case, and what I actually get passed in to **IContextAware.InjectContext()** when I instantiate a *MyChildViewModel* object in the *MyParentViewModel* constructor is a *MyParentView* object.  Not a *MyChildView* object as I was expecting and hoping.  Clearly, I need to add something to wire them up together.  Could anyone provide an example on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: is there a reason why you're using a ServiceLocator to get your child VM?  why not MEF it in?

Comment: why does `MyChildView` specify `ViewModel="MyParentViewModel"`?

Comment: what do your `MyParentView.xaml.cs` and `MyChildView.xaml.cs` files look like?

Comment: Empty apart from the InitializeComponent() call in the default constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you really want to use view-model-first then you should do:

```
[ExportViewModel("MyParentViewModel")]
public class MyParentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // Create property for your child vm
    public MyChildViewModel Child {get; private set}

    // If you do MEF use constructor injection instead of servicelocator
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyParentViewModel(MyChildViewModel child)
    {
        this.Child = child;
    }
 }
```

then define a datatemplate for your childvm

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyChildViewModel}">
     <view:MyChildViewUserControl />
 </DataTemplate>
```

in your MainView you know where you want to show the child data, otherwise you wouldn't need the child property ;) so simply put a ContentControl where the Child data should go and bind to your property.

e.g.

```
<TabControl>
   <TabItem Header="MyChildData">
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding Child}" />
   </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

PS: Code is written without IDE, so errors possible :)

Comment: Thanks for this, that was very clear. However, having implemented this, I realise now that view-model-first approach may be a bad idea when using MEF with MEFedMVVM. I am effectively circumventing the built-in exporting/importing provisions of MEFedMVVM that wires up the views and view models and instead using the standard WPF internals to wire them up through DataTemplates with DataType set. I think this is nice in that it keeps views out of view models, but using a view-first approach and injecting or instantiating views in the view model is acceptable if the design allows it.